# Show a second dropdown based on previous dropdown .in Code igniter

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, codeigniter

I have two dropdown boxes, actually I have done this functionality by using jquery and ajax by calling an id that if I select one thing it will appear on second select box  but the main problem I am facing is that I am using a template where a select box uses some class name called "cho" as if I don't use this class obviously my select box look wired so I like the style of it .So if I use this class in my second select box where the result display then the functionality wont work but if I don't use the class then it will work  so what I want is: 
I want to use the css class and implement the functionality too I checked in every css file but I cant find cho class  so what I think that if I cant change the css file may be there is the way in jquery that I'll resolve this issue.

This is my first select box ,where select box and css working fine.

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id', $records2, '#', 'id="category" class =  "cho"');?>
```

2nd select box -without css ..functionality successfull

```
   <?php echo form_dropdown('item_id', $records3, '#', 'id="items"'); ?>
```

With css--functionality wont work but css do:

```
   <?php echo form_dropdown('item_id', $records3, '#', 'id="items" class = "cho"'); ?>
```

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $('#category').change(function(){ 
            $("#items > option").remove(); 
            var category_id = $('#category').val();  
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "stockInController/get_Items/"+category_id, 

                success: function(items) 
                {
                    $.each(items,function(item_id,item_name) 
                    {
                        var opt = $('<option />'); 
                        opt.val(item_id);
                        opt.text(item_name);
                        $('#items').append(opt); 
                    });
                }                 
            });             
        });
     });        
 </script>
```

html file source of two dropdown

```
   <div class="controls">
 <select name="cat_id" id="category" class = "cho">
         <option value="1">jeans</option>
         <option value="2">shirts</option>
     </select>
     <br />
   </div>
</div>
```

Items: 
       
             
              sdf
              bello
              gamer
              dsf
              blue

Comment: Show us your dropdown page source.Just select those two dropdown and right-click and click view selected source.it seems that it Jquery or Javascript might be removing your ID and Placing their custom one.

Comment: yeah i am thinking so .. thats y i am is a=there any possibility that i can unblock it through jquery .. okk wait until i put files into temporary server so you can see it

Comment: Just show your page source may be we can find an alternative.

Comment: ok i updated my question ... you can see the source..because i am using the cho class in 2nd select box so from this source functionality is not working

Comment: Your items id is not disturbed. Did you get any error in your firebug console? Or do you have multiple ID's named items?

Comment: if i use the firbug then it displays the cho class like this "class="cho chzn-done"

Comment: Did you find its ID in the firebug?

Comment: yeah i think so .. because they select box are ina for each loop ..and the values are coming from database ..so i think there ids are same

Comment: whose id ? i didnt get u ?

Comment: items ID ... Also try selecting through name and see if it works.I hope you don't have more than one input with name item_id on that page.

Comment: selecting from name :o how can i do that.. i am selecting through javascript .. where only i think we can catch value only through id or class dont we?

Comment: You can select even through name like class or ID check my below answer.

Comment: or if u have a solution then please edit my question so i can understand more clearly

Comment: thanks ..but your code is working fine but without adding class ... if i add the class then it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried firebug or any other similar tool to find out your 'cho' class. Try this code also

```
$("#items").addClass("cho");
```

Comment: yeah i have done that ..it will show me class like that in html .. "cho chzn-done " do i upload on temporary server so you see it ... because i am running the site on localhost

Comment: i have done your code too ... css working but functionality dont

Answer (score 0):

OK try selecting through name:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#category').change(function(){ 
        $('select[id="items_chzn"] > option').remove(); 
        var category_id = $('#category').val();  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "stockInController/get_Items/"+category_id, 

            success: function(items) 
            {
                $.each(items,function(item_id,item_name) 
                {
                    var opt = $('<option />'); 
                    opt.val(item_id);
                    opt.text(item_name);
                    $('select[id="items_chzn"]').append(opt); 
                });
            }

        });

    });
 });




        </script>
```

If you are still having an issue try using an alert in the function after the ajax call.

Comment: yeah same issue.. code works only without css ... and if i do this alert(item_id); or alert(item_name)..the alert box wont comes up ... and if i do simple like alert("hello").. then it pop up

Comment: Just after opt.text(item_name); add alert(opt); and see whats the value printed.Also it will  be nice if you can show the page source where class is "class="cho chzn-done"

Comment: this is what firebug showing<div id="items_chzn" class="chzn-container 
         chzn-container-single"    style="width:220px;"> 
   
   
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="0">                 <div>
   <b>   
   </b>
  </div>
    </a>
     <div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 218px; top: 24px;">
     <div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 183px;" tabindex="-1"></div><ul class="chzn-results">
    <li id="items_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">
    hello
   </li>

Comment: There is the issue items is changed to items_chzn. Rename all your items to  items_chzn.

Comment: ,,what should i rename  id or class or what ? i ididnt get you .

Comment: Wait I guess some thing weird is happening. The input select is gone.You need to show all the code. I think its converting the select in the form of div.

Comment: <?php echo form_dropdown('item_id', $records3, '#', 'id="items" class = "cho"'); ?>                        should i have to change here something also ... because i copied ur answer butt still it didnt work

Comment: Can you show from where you are using the design? I guess its converting your dropdown into div and ul li.

Comment: i think i missed something ,... look this ..this is before the div id ="items_chzn ...sorry for this mistake                                            <select name="item_id" id="items" class="cho chzn-done" style="display: none;">
<option value="1">sdf</option>
<option value="2">bello</option>
<option value="3">gamer</option>
<option value="4">dsf</option>
<option value="5">blue</option>
</select>

Comment: yeah sure       http://themeforest.net/item/neat-admin-responsive-admin-template/full_screen_preview/2725566...

Comment: I can't see its asking me to login ....but you need to check its javascript and its manual as now its not the dropdown anymore.Your design is hiding the dropdown and creating a custom one using divs and ul li.

Comment: username :admin  and password is admin ...okk  i am working on this for two days ... can i post you js script ?

Comment: Omg  change your username and password and don't ever post username and password of your login credentials in the public.Delete it.

Comment: Just download the Dropdown and upload somewhere else and give it to me i will check it whenever i get time.

Comment: boy this is not my web app .. its just a demo ... which is online

Comment: http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com/select%20box/myforms.html                       here you can also see this from firebug ... if you want to download the js files ..download here  http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com