# dynamic dropdown with two selects jquery javascript

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, codeigniter

I am building a web app in codeigniter. I have  downloaded a template from theme forest. Now I am stuck at now a place where I don't have a way that I go back and start working on a new template. So I have two select boxes. What I want is if I select one box the results will appear on second select box. well I have done this functionality. what I am having problem is if I changed the css class of second select box then  functionality don't work.

As I like the design of select box so I dont want to get rid of css class. I want to keep both css and functionality working. I'll show my JavaScript script where I am implementing the functionality. But the main problem is the css. Because the css class name is this "cho" but when I run the script on browser it changed the class into run time and then become "cho chzn-done". You can see only this on firebug.

But if you see on view page source it will look 'cho'. and then the problem is I cant find "cho" neither "cho chzn done " in any css or in js files. So what I want is to implement the functionality on these two select boxes. I have uploaded a simple html file. you can check out this too. hope you understand what my problem really is.

```
 http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com/select%20box/myforms.html
```

and if u want to download it ..file name is select.rar

http://hello.hostingsiteforfree.com/
If any one can done this dynamic functionality on these select boxes then i'll b very thankful to him .. i don't need any JavaScript or any jquery code or want from you that you can write code from me .. i just want to just look this out .. because i think some where in css or jquery file is damaging my values.

my JavaScript file that how i am catching the values if u need this too...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#category').change(function () {
    $("#items > option").remove();
    var category_id = $('#category').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "stockInController/get_Items/" + category_id,

      success: function (items) {
        $.each(items, function (item_id, item_name) {
          var opt = $('<option />');
          opt.val(item_id);
          opt.text(item_name);
          $('#items').append(opt);
        });
      }

    });

  });
});
```

Comment: You need to reformat your question. You have `dropdown1`. On change of `dropdown1` `dropdown2` should be populated. In this process the css of `dropdown2` is not correctly applied. Is this what you are trying to tell?

Comment: nope i am not saying that ... what i am saying is if i add the css in dropdown2 then data wont come up in drop down 2 after selecting the option of . dropdown 1

Comment: Can you post the CSS class and errors if any?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334187/show-a-second-dropdown-based-on-previous-dropdown-in-code-igniter                                       there i have posted another question ... you can see some code there too .. there are no errors..actually i think u r not getting my problem .. well give some look on this last question .. and then tell what to do ..

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537872/javascript-select-city-from-selected-country-value/